# Android Binding Library Error: Como fazer um método retornar um array de IDictionary <TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

*Oi pessoal, Eu gostaria muito que alguém pudesse me ajudar com esse erro que estou recebendo quando faço a importação de um arquivo.aar, em um projeto Android Binding Library, para realizar uma integração com o serviço de uma maquininha.*

*Bom basicamente o erro se resumo no título acima*

**Esse é o código que eu desejo obter**

```
        public unsafe global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary <string, byte[]> [] GetSlots ()
        {
            const string __id = "getSlots.()[Ljava/util/HashMap;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>));
            } finally {
            }
        }
```

**Esse é o código que eu estou obtendo**

```
        public unsafe global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary <string, byte[]> GetSlots ()
        {
            const string __id = "getSlots.()[Ljava/util/HashMap;";
            try {
                var __rm = _members.InstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (__id, this, null);
                return (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>));
            } finally {
            }
        }
```

Como podem ver, eu preciso de um método que retorne um array `IDictionary<string, byte[]> []` e estou recebendo um `IDictionary<string, byte[]>`

***Esse é o código que está no metadata.xml***

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='br.com.uol.pagseguro.plugpagservice.wrapper']/class[@name='PlugPagNFCResult']/method[@name='getSlots' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary &lt;string, byte[]&gt;</attr>`

- Porém toda vez que eu coloco o `[]`, depois do `>`, ele não aparace para formar um array! *
- Poderiam me ajudar com isso?*

Comment: Tem certeza que essa API está tentando retornar vários array de dicionários, ao invés de um único dicionário com várias linhas?

Comment: Sim esse é o retorno do método que é gerado quando eu dou um build no projeto

```return (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (__rm.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (global::System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>));```

Comment: Dei uma olhada na documentação da API e realmente é um array de dicionários. Tente editar o metadata.xml e colocar um [] depois do &gt;

Comment: Toda vez que eu coloco o `[]`, depois do `>`, o sinal `[]` não  aparace no código gerado. É como se ele não aceitasse mais caractere depois do `>`.
Esse foi ó código que eu coloquei no metadata.xml
`<attr path="/api/package[@name='br.com.uol.pagseguro.plugpagservice.wrapper']/class[@name='PlugPagNFCResult']/method[@name='getSlots' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary&lt;string,byte[]&gt;[]</attr>`